# SVG logo changing color when scrolling the page: should I use two different SVG files or change its color with JS?

Tags: svg

My logo is an SVG file that I output on my page using `echo file_get_contents()`. Its color needs to change when user scrolls down the page. Should I use two versions of the SVG file (with two different colors set therein) or change the color on the fly using JS? Which one of these two solutions is the most widely accepted?

Comment: I'd recommend JS. Do you want an example?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a basic JS example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Logo Scroll</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id=myDiv style=width:100px;height:1000px;background:gainsboro>
 <svg width=100 height=100>
 <circle id=myLogo fill="red" stroke="none" cx=50 cy=50 r=30 />
</svg>
</div>
<script>
document.onscroll=function()
{
if(window.pageYOffset>10)
    myLogo.setAttribute("fill","blue")
else
    myLogo.setAttribute("fill","red")
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```